# Products with only one available colour in stock - SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I have a table that lists thousands of products. A product can be either Standard (123450.000.000), one colour (123456.BLA.000), one size (123456.000.LAR) or both colour and size (123456.BLA.LAR).

A product can have multiple colours (123456.BLA.000, 123456.YEL.OOO etc etc). I am trying to do a query that brings back a product that has multiple colours but only one colour in stock i.e. ProductQTY = 1 and the remaining colours are out of stock.

All I have been able to come up with is the query below but this just brings back all 'variant' products that have 1 in stock. What do I have to add or change to make it bring back results whereby a product has different colours but only ONE of those colours are in stock and the remaining are out of stock? Do I need to do a UNION?

```
select *
from Product
where productcode NOT LIKE ('%000.000')
AND ProductQTY = '1'
```

Comment: Show table structures, sample data and what dbms you are using.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, that's a terrible structure.  Store color and size information in separate tables, don't make them part of one massive variable.

Second, you want to do a query that selects Product IDs (1-6, looks like) that have a count > 1 with color present and the sum of their quantities is 1 exactly (according to your question - if that one record could have a qty>1 and still be okay, this is a little more complicated).

```
select * from product where substr(product,1,6) in (
select substr(product,1,6) from product 
where not (product like '%.000.%')
group by 1
having count(1) > 1
and sum(ProductQTY)=1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The question would be much easier if you would split up the properties in different columns. But you could do that in a query aswell:

```
select code from 
  (select substring(productcode,-3) as size,
   substring(productcode,-7,3) as colour,
   substring(productcode,0,len(prodcutcode)-7) as code
  from product) t
group by code
having sum(productQTY) = 1 

//or count(*) = 1 to get all unique ones
```

Comment: How does that get records with multiple color records and one in stock?

Comment: select * from product where substring(productcode,0,len(prodcutcode)-7) in (my query)

Comment: That gets color, but it does not get records where there are 2 or more colors for the same product code.

Comment: Is there any chance that you may know Joe?